# How to install glassfish into netbeans

Tags: glassfish, netbeans6.7

Glassfish had already been installed into Netbeans. But I forgot the password and username. (It wasn't `admin`, `adminadmin`) So I reinstalled to desktop. I followed [glassfish configuration](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/v2.1-b60e.html) After that I tried to associate Netbeans and glassfish. First I created Netbeans 6.7.1 Tools/ servers / add Server /  glassfish v2.1
server location is chosen where I download and configured the glassfish file. Register local domain was chosen. And then I clicked next.

Domain folder was chosen c:\Sun\AppSer\Domains\domain1 and then I clicked next. Admin:`admin` password:`adminadmin` and clicked finish.

But it doesn't work. When I run a project, it gives exceptions

```
Domain domain1 failed to startup. Please check the server log for more details.

 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 8686; nested exception is: 
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 8686; nested exception is: 
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
CORE5061: Exception : 
com.sun.appserv.server.ServerLifecycleException: WEB0106: An error occurred while   stopping the web container
Caused by: LifecycleException:  WEB0103: This web container has not yet been started
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.stop(WebContainer.java:912)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PEWebContainer.stopInstance(PEWebContainer.java:815)
        ... 10 more
CORE5051: Shutting down all J2EE applications ...
CORE5068 :  Stopping all J2EE Connector 1.5 Compliant resource adapters ...
CORE 5061 : Resource adapters Stop() Complete
CORE5052: Application shutdown complete.
CORE5061: Exception : 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can I get rid of these exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 8686;
```

The server tries to listen on a port that is already in use. This happens if another server is already running or did not correctly release its ressources.

If another server runs on the same host, either stop the other server or configure another port.

If the port is blocked because of incorrect cleanup, try to kill all java processes and restart NetBeans/Glassfish. If this does not help, restart your computer.